# What happens when non-static function declaration follows static function declaration?

Tags: c, function, static, linkage

The following compiles:

```
static int foo() { return 1; }
int foo();
```

But, will it always compile? Is the behavior in this case well defined? And what does it means when a non-static prototype follows a static declaration?

Comment: note: neither of these are prototypes  (use `(void)` instead of `()` to make a prototype)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes it will compile and behavior is well defined. Since `foo` is declared `static` earlier than `int foo();`<sup>**1**</sup>, `foo` has internal linkage.

#### C11: 6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers (p4):

> For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier `extern` in a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible,<sup>31)</sup> **if the prior declaration specifies internal or external linkage, the linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the same as the linkage specified at the prior declaration**. [...]

and the foot note states that:

> 31)  As specified in 6.2.1, the later declaration might hide the prior declaration.

---

<sub>**1**. If no storage class is specified , the function is assumed to have external linkage.  Standard says: *If the declaration of an identifier for a function has no storage-class specifier, its linkage
is determined exactly as if it were declared with the storage-class specifier `extern` -- 6.2.2 (p5).*</sub>

Comment: But, my prototype was _not_ defined with `extern`.

Answer (score 0):

By default functions are global. So making it

```
static int foo() { return 1; }
```

The function `foo()` is just visible within this file. Since you just have the declaration `int foo();` this is fine and well defined if you have a definition for the same `int foo(){ return 2;}` then you will get **redefinition error**.

As stated by **@haccks**

> 6.2.1, the later declaration might hide the prior declaration.

Note the difference between declaration and definition.